# Trying to open WebView in TabHost

Tags: android, webview, android-tabhost

Ok so i'm trying to create a small app that opens 3 different webviews within 3 different tabs. At the moment I Have my tabhost created ok and a separate class for my webview but when I open the app it doesn't display.

Tabhost code

```
public class HelloTabWidgetActivity extends TabActivity {
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, HelloWebViewActivity.class);

    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("albums").setIndicator("News",
            res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_albums))
        .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    // Do the same for the other tabs
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, SongsActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("songs").setIndicator("SaintsTV",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_songs))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ArtistsActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("artists").setIndicator("Fixtures",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
}
```

}

webview code

```
public class HelloWebViewActivity extends Activity {
    WebView mWebView;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
    }
}
```

I can't see a problem and I have read other peoples posts regarding TabHostContentFactory but I have no idea how to make it load the webview when the app opens. Any help would be greatly received.

The above code is based on the HelloWebView tutorial and the HelloTabWidget tutorial

Answer (score 2):

I had tried the same things sometime back and later figured out that I did not declare appropraite Internet access permissions for the app. That was the reason, webview in the tabhost was getting blank and there was no error in the Logcat either.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Adding above lines to the AndroidManifest.xml had resolved my problem.

Comment: Yes, the ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the problem itself it's in the main layout, because I run your code fine wiht the only modification:

```
 public class HelloWebViewActivity extends Activity {
    WebView mWebView;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        mWebView = new WebView(this);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());

        setContentView(mWebView);
    }
}
```

this is to get you starting,

I suggest to use the Tabhost layout file for only the tab and the webview controller (and other intent layouts) should be in other layout files. For this you can use the tutorial:http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=136

I hope this helps

Comment: Hi thanks for that, i'm a little new at the android developing and java any chance you could expand your answer a little more as i'm unsure where to put the code.

Comment: I detailed in the answer, I hope it helps. That tutorial is very good, you can find there everything you need to have a cool tabhost ;)