# Second WebView not loading

Tags: android

Hi I am making a small android app for a **Youtube** channel and I have got a tab host which holds **two different activities** both of which run a web view on creation.

I have a web view client handling external links (one for each web view activity).

The First Tab Loads the web page fine but the second is just blank when I switch to it from the tab how do I fix this?

**Here's the body code for the main activity which handles the tabs.**

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
    TabSpec youtubespec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Youtube");
    // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
    youtubespec.setIndicator("Youtube", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.youtube_icon));
    Intent youtubeIntent = new Intent(this, Youtube.class);
    youtubespec.setContent(youtubeIntent);

    TabSpec websitespec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Website");
    // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
    websitespec.setIndicator("Website", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.website_icon));
    Intent websiteIntent = new Intent(this, Website.class);
    websitespec.setContent(websiteIntent);

    tabHost.addTab(youtubespec); 
    tabHost.addTab(websitespec); 

}
```

**Here is the code for the first web view.**
    WebView web1;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.youtube);
    web1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webyt);
    web1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient1());
    WebSettings webSettings = web1.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webSettings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(false);
    webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true); 
    web1.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    web1.loadUrl("http://www.youtube.com/user/theanykeyyt");

}


@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && web1.canGoBack()) {
        web1.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    // If it wasn't the Back key or there's no web page history, bubble up to the default
    // system behavior (probably exit the activity)
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

**Here is the code for the second web view**

```
WebView web2; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.website);
    web2 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.websitea);
    web2.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient2());
    WebSettings webSettings = web2.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webSettings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(false);
    webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true); 
    web2.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    web2.loadUrl("http://theanykeyyt.wix.com/theanykey");


}
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && web2.canGoBack()) {
        web2.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    // If it wasn't the Back key or there's no web page history, bubble up to the default
    // system behavior (probably exit the activity)
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

**Here's the web client**

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
   view.loadUrl(url); 
   return true;

}
```

Comment: I don't find any kind of problem with your code. I have tested it and its working great on my side. Have you provided internet permission in your manifest file?

Comment: hey i fixed it just needed to add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

Comment: I don't understand why `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />` permission? It should work only with `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` permission.

Comment: yeah i dont know either just saw it on here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812791/trying-to-open-webview-in-tabhost

Comment: Alright Great :) But its working with `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` on my side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed just had to add this to manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```